# Python & Redis - Flask API that sets/reads values from Redis problem

Tags: python, database, api, flask, redis

The situation is the following: I have a Flask web server, and I need to develop a new API endpoint for it (POST/GET), which would update/read a server status.

My POST API requires an input like this:

```
{
    "name": <name_of_the_server>,
    "serverUrl" <url_of_the_server>,
    "available": true/false
}
```

I want to save this information in Redis for a week. I save the whole JSON from the API request as a dictionary value in Redis. I dump and load it with pickle. **The key is the "name" paramater.**

I also have a GET API endpoint, in which I can specify the name of the server, and get the status information about it. Hence, Python checks in Redis for the key, containing the name of the server (given by the user through the API), and returns the value (the dictionary with all of the information that was saved previously).

This is all good, and works as intended. However, through the GET API, I should also be able to search for server status with the server URL (as well as the server name).

So far my solution is like this:

```
// Redis is a class, I previously instantiated
redis.set(server_name, server_data, ex=time_to_live)
redis.set(server_url, server_data, ex=time_to_live)
```

I set two keys, containing the exact same information. Through the GET endpoint, this gives me the chance to check server status by using either the server name or the server URL, as they return the same value. Also, they have the same expiry date, and are always updated together.

This works, however I feel this is more of a "cheat" solution, so I would want to ask for an advice if I should keep it that way, or if there is a better way to achieve the same functionality. Thank you in advance!